# Funçao Aggregate no R

Tags: r

Estou utilizando a função `aggregate` para agrupar alguns dados. Porém, estou utilizando apenas uma variável para somar. Gostaria de utilizar mais de uma variável. Isso é possível?
Estou utilizando o seguinte exemplo:

```
TESTE = aggregate(VALOR ~ REFERENCIA + GRUPO_COPA + CIDADE, data=DADOS,FUN=sum)
```

Gostaria de utilizar variável `QTDE` junto a `VALOR` para somar, ou seja, acrescentar mais uma coluna, ficando as seguintes colunas:

```
REFERENCIA, GRUPO_COPA, CIDADE, VALOR, QTDE
```

É possível no aggregate ou em outra função este exemplo?
Grato.

**Edit**

Vejam aí meu exemplo utilizando o dput(DADOS):

```
structure(list(REFERENCIA = c("JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017" ), GRUPO_COPA = c("AZUL", "AZUL", "AMARELO", "AMARELO", "VERDE", "VERDE", "VERDE", "AZUL", "AZUL"), CIDADE = c("SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "RJ", "BSB", "BSB", "BSB", "SP"), VALOR = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000), QTDE = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17)), .Names = c("REFERENCIA", "GRUPO_COPA", "CIDADE", "VALOR", "QTDE"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Gostaria que agrupasse este conjunto de dados (semelhante ao `aggregate` ou similar) somando as colunas `VALOR` e `QTDE`.

Comment: Uma dica: é muito mais fácil conseguir ajuda aqui fornecendo um conjunto de dados. Não é necessário ser o teu conjunto original completo. Pode ser apenas uma parte dele. Para compartilhar o teu conjunto de dados, rode `dput(DADOS)` e cole o resultado no corpo da pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução usando `aggregate()` é informar `.` na parte esquerda da formula:

```
dados <- structure(list(REFERENCIA = c("JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "JAN_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017", "FEV_2017" ), GRUPO_COPA = c("AZUL", "AZUL", "AMARELO", "AMARELO", "VERDE", "VERDE", "VERDE", "AZUL", "AZUL"), CIDADE = c("SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "RJ", "BSB", "BSB", "BSB", "SP"), VALOR = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000), QTDE = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17)), .Names = c("REFERENCIA", "GRUPO_COPA", "CIDADE", "VALOR", "QTDE"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
aggregate( . ~ REFERENCIA + GRUPO_COPA + CIDADE, FUN = sum, data = dados)
```

Answer (score 6):

Eu sugiro que você use o pacote `dplyr` para fazer este tipo de operação.
Segue um exemplo de uso que resolveria o seu problema:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
  summarise(
    valor = sum(mpg),
    qtd = n()
  )
```

Dentro da função `group_by` você indica quais são as variáveis pelas quais você quer fazer as agregações (No seu caso seria `REFERENCIA + GRUPO_COPA + CIDADE`). Na função `summarise` você indica a conta que você precisa fazer para agregar. Em especial, a função `n()` retorna a contagem de linhas, que é o que você queria calcular.

Uma boa referência para aprender mais sobre `dplyr` é o livro [*R for Data Science*](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/), principalmente [**este capítulo**](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html).

Comment: Bom dia. Infelizmente não deu certo. Aparece uma mensagem dizendo que o número de linhas não deve superior a 32. Você teria outra sugestão?

Comment: talvez porque na sintaxe do dplyr não seja `REFERENCIA + GRUPO_COPA + CIDADE`, mas  `group_by(REFERENCIA, GRUPO_COPA, CIDADE)`. Como o @Marcus Nunes falou, `dput(DADOS)` nos ajudaria a te ajudar.

Comment: E para subtrair ao invés de somar ?

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou claro como você queria o resultado, então fiz as duas soluções possíveis para a coluna quantidade.

Somando os valores conforme as quantidades:

```
aggregate((VALOR * QTDE) ~ REFERENCIA + GRUPO_COPA + 
CIDADE, data=da,FUN=sum)

REFERENCIA GRUPO_COPA CIDADE (VALOR * QTDE)
1   FEV_2017       AZUL    BSB         120000
2   FEV_2017      VERDE    BSB         157000
3   FEV_2017      VERDE     RJ          45000
4   JAN_2017    AMARELO     SP          43000
5   FEV_2017       AZUL     SP         153000
6   JAN_2017       AZUL     SP           7000
```

Somando os valores conforme as quantidades e informando as quantidades unitárias:

```
aggregate(cbind(valor = VALOR * QTDE, QTDE) ~ REFERENCIA + 
GRUPO_COPA + CIDADE, data=da,FUN=sum)

REFERENCIA GRUPO_COPA CIDADE  valor QTDE
1   FEV_2017       AZUL    BSB 120000   15
2   FEV_2017      VERDE    BSB 157000   24
3   FEV_2017      VERDE     RJ  45000    9
4   JAN_2017    AMARELO     SP  43000   12
5   FEV_2017       AZUL     SP 153000   17
6   JAN_2017       AZUL     SP   7000    4
```